# No return from the wrapping function of a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am struggling with the concept of the **promise / await** functions here. I have two functions. The first one is wrapping around a promise. The second one is used to execute the first one and retrieve the result of the first function, and then chain it to the next function to be executed inside the second function.

However, I always get the error that "cannot have .then() after undefine", when running the second function. I do not know why not the chain awaits for the first function to finish.

**First function:**

```
const poolGetConnectReadCol = (query) => {
  return pool.promise().query(query, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err; // this console.log works fine here.
    console.log('res=>', res);
  });
};
```

**Second function:**

```
const addEmployee = async (commandLinePrompt) => {
  const query1 = `SELECT
      CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS Avaliable_Manager 
      FROM employees`;
  const data = await poolGetConnectReadCol(query1);
  console.log('data=>', data); // this console.log does not run at all
};
```

Comment: That's because what you return from `poolGetConnectReadCol ` is not a promise, and you cannot run `await` on a non-promise. I suggest you find a way to make sure `.query(...)` returns a Promise. Or you can drop the source code to let someone take a look at how it is all implemented :)

Comment: You're mixing a bunch of paradigms. Since you're doing database stuff, this article (I wrote) might help and is basically just a couple of good Node.js patterns for working with MySQL and async/await: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/